# I'm trying to create an application that works with voice commands with vb.net, I want it to work as "alexa"

Tags: vb.net, speech-recognition, grammar, rules, voice

I'm trying to create an application that works with voice commands with vb.net. I want it to work as "Alexa" and therefore have a keyword and then the commands, but the keyword and commands must be written by the user.

How do I add strings to the grammar without having to first pass them to the rule? (sorry for bad english i'm italian)

Here's my code so far:

```
Imports System.Speech

Public Class Form1
    Dim WithEvents reco As New Recognition.SpeechRecognitionEngine
    Dim WithEvents reco2 As New Recognition.SpeechRecognitionEngine
    Dim recallWord As String
    Dim c As Integer = 0
    Dim comandoWord(c) As String
    Dim comandoV As New Recognition.SrgsGrammar.SrgsOneOf
    Dim recallV As New Recognition.SrgsGrammar.SrgsOneOf
    Dim gram As New Recognition.SrgsGrammar.SrgsDocument
    Dim rules As New Recognition.SrgsGrammar.SrgsRule("a")
    Dim rules2 As New Recognition.SrgsGrammar.SrgsRule("b")
    Dim recording As Boolean
    Dim gram2 As New Recognition.SrgsGrammar.SrgsDocument

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        reco.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice()
        reco2.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btIns_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btIns.Click
        c = c + 1
        ReDim comandoWord(c)
        recallWord = txtRecall.Text
        comandoWord(c) = txtComando.Text


        Dim recallC As New Recognition.SrgsGrammar.SrgsItem(recallWord)
        recallV.Items.Add(recallC)
        rules.Add(recallV)
        gram.Rules.Add(rules)
        gram.Root = rules
        reco.LoadGrammar(New Recognition.Grammar(gram))


        Dim comandoC As New Recognition.SrgsGrammar.SrgsItem(comandoWord(c))
        comandoV.Items.Add(comandoC)
        rules2.Add(comandoV)
        gram2.Rules.Add(rules2)
        gram2.Root = rules2
        reco2.LoadGrammar(New Recognition.Grammar(gram2))


        reco.RecognizeAsync()
        reco2.RecognizeAsync()
    End Sub

    Private Sub reco_speechRecognized(ByVal sender As Object, e As System.Speech.Recognition.RecognitionEventArgs) Handles reco.SpeechRecognized
        If e.Result.Text = recallWord Then
            MsgBox(e.Result.Text)
            recording = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub reco2_speechRecognized(ByVal sender As Object, e As System.Speech.Recognition.RecognitionEventArgs) Handles reco2.SpeechRecognized
        If recording = True Then
            If e.Result.Text = comandoWord(1) Then
                MsgBox(e.Result.Text)
                recording = False
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub reco_recognizecompleted(ByVal sender As Object, e As System.Speech.Recognition.RecognizeCompletedEventArgs) Handles reco.RecognizeCompleted
        reco.RecognizeAsync()
    End Sub

    Private Sub reco2_recognizecompleted(ByVal sender As Object, e As System.Speech.Recognition.RecognizeCompletedEventArgs) Handles reco2.RecognizeCompleted
        reco2.RecognizeAsync()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you correctly, you are looking to create an **object** called **"Choices"** which represents a component of a phrase that can have one of several values. This is vital for speech recognition **"GrammarBuilder"**. The following is an example of an established Grammar in VB.NET that I tested and compiled for you. I only have one command in it.If you wish to add more, do this: ("Activate Scarlett", "Run Notepad")) Just be sure you last word doesn't have a comma. I hope it will suffice.

```
Imports System.Globalization
Imports System.Speech
Imports System.Speech.Recognition
Imports System.Threading

Public Class Sentinal
    Private WithEvents Sentinal As New SpeechRecognitionEngine
    Public synth As New Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer
    Dim grammerBuilder As New DictationGrammar()

    Private Sub Sentinal_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Try
            Dim commandChoices As New Choices
            Dim grammarBuilder As New GrammarBuilder
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = New CultureInfo("en-EN")
            commandChoices.Add(New String("Activate Scarlett")) '<add more
            grammarBuilder.Append(commandChoices)
            Sentinal.RequestRecognizerUpdate()
            Dim gr As New Grammar(grammarBuilder)
            Sentinal.LoadGrammarAsync(gr)
            Sentinal.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice()
            Sentinal.RecognizeAsync()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Sentinal_RecognizeCompleted(sender As Object, e As RecognizeCompletedEventArgs) Handles Sentinal.RecognizeCompleted
        Sentinal.RecognizeAsync()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Sentinal_SpeechRecognized(sender As Object, e As SpeechRecognizedEventArgs) Handles Sentinal.SpeechRecognized
        Select Case e.Result.Text
            Case "Activate Scarlett"

                'Place your event here

             Case "Run Notepad"
                
                 'Event Here

        End Select
    End Sub


End Class
```

[Choices Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/enus/dotnet/api/system.speech.recognition.choices?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 0):

Also, you mentioned you are Italian, so I am going to assume you are in Italy. If this is the case make this adjustment to:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = New CultureInfo("en-EN")
```

Change to:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = New CultureInfo("it-IT")
```

Answer (score 0):

I designed Scarlett's program that you are asking about.
You can easily create a text file that holds your commands from Choices:

> recEngine.LoadGrammar(New Grammar(New GrammarBuilder(New
> Choices(File.ReadAllLines("C:\Users\justin.ross\source\repos\ScarlettCenturium\Scarlett
> Centurium\Scarlett Centurium\Commands.txt")))))

I left the link to my repository. Just locate `Form1.vb` and open it. It will answer your question.

```
  https://github.com/Rythorian77/Scarlett-Centurium-XI1/commit/6745552659f935881852151d5f880d2e6886f6cd
```